# How to list all command line flags available in python modules and what they do

Tags: python, pytest

Like with pytest for example. I see it's used with -vs. Is there a way I can list all available command line flag options and see what they do? They don't show up in help(pytest), nor man pytest on CLI, and searching with dashes in online docs doesn't show them. I'm sure I could find the info if I keep searching online, but I'm looking for a quick way to get the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `--help` to list the possible CLI flags

```
python -m pytest --help
```

This information is also available in [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#command-line-flags)